# Call a function before a specific major mode starts

Tags: hooks, advice

I have a setup function that I want to run before I use `pdb`/`gud` to debug a Python script. I know about `gud-mode-hook` which runs after the debugger starts (too late) and `change-major-mode-hook` which, if I understand correctly, runs when you change major modes but *before* the major mode hook for the new mode (early enough, but will run in cases I don't want it to). **How can I have a function called *before* a specific major mode is initialized?**

So for my particular use case the flow would be something like:

`M-x pdb` -> `(my-setup-function)` is called -> `pdb` starts (i.e., it's hooks are run etc.)

So far I have tried doing this with major mode hooks `pdb-mode-hook` and `gud-mode-hook` but then the setup doesn't happen in time, and is only available the *next* time I run `pdb`. At one point I tried to do it with advice as well, but was not successful (potentially, because I did it wrong). This is what I tried (though I am confused as to whether or not this counts as `advice`):

```
 (add-function :before (pdb) #'my-setup-function)
```

...which I based on a snippet from the [Emacs Lisp Reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html):

```
(add-function :before (process-filter proc) #'my-tracing-function)
```

Obviously, I have not set this up right, and I get the message that `(pdb) is not a valid place expression` when I evaluate it. Even though (because?) the documentation for `add-function` is very detailed, I have a lot of trouble understanding how to use it properly.

Comment: Could you add a basic test to a function you add to the `change-major-mode-hook`?  Eg, `(defun my-setup-function () (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode) (do-my-setup-stuff)))`, and then `(add-hook 'change-major-mode-hook #'my-setup-function)`.

Comment: @Dan I tried this, but couldn't get it to work. Shouldn't this call `my-setup-function` whenever you change from `python-mode` to another mode? Maybe I am misunderstanding the chain of events, but trying it this way it seems like my function just never fires period.

Comment: What about `(defadvice :before ..`. Ugly, I know...

Comment: `defadvice` would be my answer as well. Why don't you share what you tried? Maybe someone will see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @db48x, see the last part of my updated question for something I tried.

Comment: @JonKåreHellan that sounds very close to what I had in mind, but I am not sure how to set it up right. Also, I am not concerned with whether it is ugly or not, as long as it works. But what is ugly about it? Is there a reason you shouldn't advice functions like this or something? I am still very new to elisp

Comment: I posted some working(?) code as an answer, hopefully it can help. Why it is ugly? Well, the emacs lisp manual does have reservations. See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html#Advising-Named-Functions

Comment: elethan: FYI your understanding of `change-major-mode-hook` is correct: `major-mode` still has its original (pre-change) value at this time. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19295380 might be of interest too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do exactly what you want!
That means define a function as follows and run this function instead of `pdb`.

```el
(defun mypdb ()
  "Start `pdb' with my own setup."
  (interactive)
  (my-setup-function)
  (pdb))
```

That would be what the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Named-Functions.html#Advising-Named-Functions) suggests in another situation:

> If you simply want to change what a particular key does, it may be better to write a new command, and remap the old command’s key bindings to the new one (see Remapping Commands).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! It worked to solve my particular problem, but is also a nice pattern to know - for whatever reason, I never though about doing things this way

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work. Apparently, defadvice is old-fashioned, and we're supposed to use advice-add instead.

```
(defun jk-advice ()
  (message "Kilroy was here"))
(advice-add 'python-mode :before #'jk-advice)
```

Comment: I am not sure why, but I was not able to get advice to work for my particular use case this time, though I am glad to have this as a straightforward, simple example to use in the future. Similar to using hooks, my setup function got called too late, and only took effect the second time I used the debugger. I went with @Tobias's solution, because that worked for me. Thanks for the "advice" on `advice` though!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use a more generic hook:

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook
          (defun my-before-python-mode()
            (when (eq major-mode 'python-mode)
              (message "running before python"))))
```